# Is there a connection between "cuchillo" and "cuchara"?

Tags: etimología

Do these two words have any common root?

I looked up in the [RAE](http://rae.es/), and didn't find there any connection between these words.  According to the RAE, **cuchillo** comes from Latin *"cultellus"*, and **cuchara** comes from verb *"cuchar"*.

So it looks like there are no real connections there,  maybe it's only this, but I still see that both words share the common part *"**cuch**"*. And it seems to me that *cuchillo* also comes from *cuchar*, with just adding the suffix *-illo*.

So how come that the Latin word `cultellus` transforms itself from knife to something spoon-like?

Comment: IS there such a connection??

Comment: I think it really is just a nice coincidence.

Comment: @hippietrail maybe, but in this case, when these two words are commonly used together in daily life. `I want to believe` that they are somehow connected to each other. But I understand that I can be terribly wrong here.

Comment: I would say the roots are different. I think it is cuchill (cuchillo, cuchillazo,...) and cuchar (cucharilla, cuchara, cucharazo) so they don't have the same root.

Comment: @Juanillo that's a very good point, you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. As you say, they have different roots:

---

- `PIE` **(s)kelH-* ("to cut")

  - `Latin` *culter* ("knife; razor")

    - `Latin` *cultellus* ("small knife; dagger")

      - `Spanish` [***cuchillo***](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=cuchillo)

---

- `PIE` **kongʰ-* ("shell, mussel")

  - `Ancient Greek` κόγχη (*kónkhē*, "mussel")

    - `Ancient Greek` κοχλίας (*kokhlías*, "spiral, snail shell")

      - `Latin` *cochlea* ("snail; snail shell")

        - `Latin` *cochleāre* ("spoon")

          - `Old Spanish` *cuchar* ("spoon")

            - `Spanish` [***cuchara***](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=BXVkk8B)

---

The reason their modern forms look more similar than might be otherwise expected from their Latin roots is explained [here](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/cons.htm):

> Latin /-l/ in the *-ŭlt-* sequence developed in the same way as the syllable-final velar consonants considered in 5.1. That is, it semivocalized and then caused the following consonant to palatalize:
>
> - *cŭltĕllum* [koɫˈtεllo] > [kojˈtεllo] > [kuˈtʃjeʎo] > [kuˈtʃiʎo] *cuchillo* ‘knife’
> - *mŭltum* [ˈmoɫto] > [ˈmojto] > [ˈmutʃo] *mucho* ‘much’

---

**Source:**

<sup>*The Linguistics of Spanish: History: Consonants: 5. Semivocalization of syllable-final velars and /-l/: 5.2 Syllable final /-l/*, Ian Mackenzie</sup>

Answer (score 5):

If you follow through another step with the DRAE you'll find that it indicates the etymology of *cuchar* as the Latin word *cochleāre*; according to latin-dictionary.org this means [*spoon*](http://www.latin-dictionary.org/latin-english-online-dictionary/cochleare) and was originally a spoon for extracting snails from their shells; *snail* being *cochlea*. So actually *cuchillo* has come further in form from its Latin root (*cultell-* to *cuchill-* vs *cochle-* to *cuch-*).

Answer (score 2):

I would say the roots are different. I think it is **cuchill** (cuchillo, cuchillazo,...) and **cuchar** (cucharilla, cuchara, cucharazo) so they don't have the same root.

Comment: Juanillo, just for clarify, you should also answer the OP's specific yes/no question: is there a connection or not?

Comment: What's your reason for analysing *cuchillo* as coming from a stem *cuchill-* rather than a diminutive of *?cucho*?

Comment: @Peter Taylor It's the first time I see that word, but looking at RAE dictionary the definitions don't have anything to do with a knife (it means crooked, cat...). It would be as if you compare in English "tun", "tune" and "tunnel"... they don't have a coomon context meaning, while "cuchillo, "cuchillada", "cuchillero"... does